# Use PHP string at start of page, that were setted at the end of page

Tags: php

Is there any way to get PHP string value before it was setted. Maybe it's possible to make with substr_replace?

I need to write this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title><?php echo $monkey;></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php 
            $monkey = "I like banana!";
            echo $monkey;
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

To get this result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>I like banana!</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            I like banana!
        </body>
    </html>
```

I know I could set `$monkey` before `<html>` code, but can I declare `$monkey` at the end of page to get it at the beginning?

UPDATE:
This example not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?php title();?></title> <!-- Need result I like banana! -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
        $monkey = "I like banana!";
        function title(){
            echo "$monkey";
        }
        title();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Short answer, no you can't reference variables that don't exist yet. You say "I know I could set `$monkey` before `<html>` code", so it seems like there's some reason you don't want to do that? If you share more about the actual problem you're facing, it might be easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go!  Just use a function!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title><?php title();?></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php 
            function title(){
                $monkey = "I like banana!";
                echo $monkey;
            }
            title();
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But how can I pass `$monkey` string to function? Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the variable before you start emitting the page?

```
<?php $monkey = "I like bananas"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title><?php echo $monkey;?></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php 
            echo $monkey;
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```